# Find continent of each country

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array of continents and countries:

```
const continents = [
  {
    continent: 'Europe',
    countries: [
      'Albania',
      'Andorra',...
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Asia',
    countries: [
      'Afghanistan',
      'Bahrain',...
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Africa',
    countries: [
      'Algeria',
      'Angola',...
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Americas',
    countries: [
      'Antigua and Barbuda',
      'Bahamas',...
    ],
  },
]
```

And an array of some countries:

```
const countries = ['Angola', 'Andorra']
```

I want to iterate over countries and return an array of objects like that:

```
const result = countries.map(country => {
  return {
    continent: ??,
    country: country,
  }
})
```

How can I find the continent of each countries?

I try this:

```
const continent = continents.forEach((continent, i) => {
  const countries = continent.countries
  if (find(countries, value.country)) return continent.continent
})
```

But I get

> **[ts] Not all code paths return a value. [7030]**

Comment: Worth noting that `return` inside `.forEach` *does not do anything*. `.forEach` does not return any value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find `continent` by checking the value with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const
    continents = [{ continent: 'Europe', countries: ['Albania', 'Andorra'] }, { continent: 'Asia', countries: ['Afghanistan', 'Bahrain'] }, { continent: 'Africa', countries: ['Algeria', 'Angola'] }, { continent: 'Americas', countries: ['Antigua and Barbuda', 'Bahamas'] }],
    countries = ['Angola', 'Andorra'],
    result = countries.map(country => ({
        continent: continents.find(({ countries }) =>
            countries.includes(country)).continent,
        country,
    }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map `map` each country name country name to newObj. And then you can use `find()` method on `continents` to find out whether the `countries` array of that continent obj contains the country name or not

```js
const continents = [
  {
    continent: 'Europe',
    countries: [
      'Albania',
      'Andorra'
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Asia',
    countries: [
      'Afghanistan',
      'Bahrain'
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Africa',
    countries: [
      'Algeria',
      'Angola'
    ],
  },
  {
    continent: 'Americas',
    countries: [
      'Antigua and Barbuda',
      'Bahamas'
    ],
  },
]

const countries = ['Angola', 'Andorra']
const result = countries.map(count => {
 const obj = {country:count};
 //get the continent object from array continents which includes 'count' in its countries array
 const continentObj = continents.find(continent=>continent.countries.includes(count));
 //add continent name to the obj as continent name in continentObj
 obj.continent = continentObj.continent;
 return obj;
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

So here the idea is loop through the **`continent`** array and filter the countries which are available in countries array. Than map through the **`matchingCountry`** and create a object with desired keys and push in final output.

```js
const continents = [{ continent:'Europe',countries: ['Albania','Andorra',],},{continent: 'Asia',countries: ['Afghanistan',  'Bahrain', ],  },{continent: 'Africa',countries: ['Algeria',  'Angola',],},{continent: 'Americas',countries: [   'Antigua and Barbuda','Bahamas',],},]

const countries = ['Angola','Andorra', 'Andorra', 'Bahamas']

const output = continents.reduce((op,cur) => {
  let matchCounrty = cur.countries.filter(e =>  countries.includes(e) )
  if( matchCounrty && matchCounrty.length ){
    let desiredObject = matchCounrty.map(e => ({
      continent: cur.continent,
      country: e
    }))
    op.push(desiredObject)
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

First reduce the continents array to an object with key as continent and value as the countries array.

```
let continentObj = continents.reduce((obj,currentObj) => {
obj[currentObj.continent] = currentObj.countries 
return obj
},{})
```

Then get the continent by running a map on countries and find the continent inside the object created in the reduce step.

```
 const countryObj = countries.map(country => {
  const continent = Object.keys(continentObj).find(continentName => continentObj[continentName].indexOf(country) > -1)
 return {
  continent,
  country
}
})
console.log(countryObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple lookups, more efficient approach would be to create a lookup object :

```js
const lookup = {}, countries = ['Angola', 'Andorra'], continents = [ { continent: 'Europe', countries: [ 'Albania', 'Andorra' ], }, { continent: 'Asia', countries: [ 'Afghanistan', 'Bahrain' ], }, { continent: 'Africa', countries: [ 'Algeria', 'Angola' ], }, { continent: 'Americas', countries: [ 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Bahamas' ] } ];

for (let obj of continents)
  for (let country of obj.countries)
     lookup[country] = obj.continent;
 
const result = countries.map(country => ({ country, continent: lookup[country] }));

console.log( result );
console.log( lookup );
```